# Region of convergence: Complex vs Real valued power series.

Tags: complex-analysis

The real valued power series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-x_0)^n$$

converges when: $|x-x_0|<R$ and diverges when $|x-x_0|>R$. I want to find the region of convergence for the complex valued series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n$$

Which, is this not obviously $|z-z_0|<R$? What method to use to prove the result?

Comment: By basic properties of power series the radius of convergence is $R$ and the circle of convergnec is precisely $\{z: |z-z_0| <R\}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Correct, but I believe the idea is to give it in terms of $R$ of the real valued series. Although I may be misreading the question.